# AJAX Post never makes it to ASP.Net Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I know this call works, because I can see it in the xhr headers when debugging. However, the data never seems to hit the controller and I can't figure out why. My ASP.Net skills are pretty limited so I'll post everything I've done.

JS:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(myObj)
$.ajax({
    url: '/Things/UploadInfo',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('success')
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('error')
    }
});
```

**[ThingsController.cs](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k7Rlt6)**

string data keeps returning `null`

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadInfo(string data)
{
    InfoModel someInfo = new InfoModel();

    return Json(new { status = "success" });
}
```

InfoModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjectName.Models
{
    public class InfoModel
    {
        public class Attr
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string age { get; set; }
            public string sex { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Content" is (when using the default template) a folder where your images, CSS, etc. lives. Did you rename that folder? If not, it normally won't get mapped by the routing engine.

Comment: Where does that ajax call live? Are you using a script tag within a view?

Comment: It's within a Vue.js build. The built files are within a view.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by simplifying your ajax call. The setup you're using is required for WebForms, but the MVC and WebApi frameworks don't require those extra options (with the exception of `crossDomain`, but it doesn't look like you're actually doing anything CORS-related).

Here's what I would use:

```
$.post('/Things/UploadInfo', myObj)
    .done(function (response, status, jqxhr) {
      console.log('success')
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, status, error) {
        console.log('error')
    });
```

This assumes that `myObj` is either a JSON object or can be implicitly serialized.

Your `UploadInfo` action should probably have either a model to bind, or the individual parameters you're expecting. Let's say you had this model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then your action would look like

```
public ActionResult UploadInfo(Foo model)
```

or

```
public ActionResult UploadInfo(int id, string name)
```

and both would be mapped by the model binder. As a side note, you can leave the return type (mostly) generic - `JsonResult` inherits `ActionResult`, so you can still use `return Json()` when the return type is `ActionResult`.

If you're expecting varying JSON objects, then the data object you supply to the ajax call would be something like:

```
var data = {
    data: myObj
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. For your ajax url, use "http://localhost:portNumber/Things/UploadInfo"
2. Change your UploadInfo parameter to (InfoModel data).
3. Use a utility like Chrome extension Advanced Rest Client and make sure you can hit a breakpoint in your method.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US

Comment: Thanks for the info. I changed my ajax url and the parameter info, but I'm getting the same results. ARC is giving a 200 OK status as well.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in your method when testing with ARC?  When/if it broke into your method, was the parameter data null?  Empty?